# help - advise request

Tags: ssl

I have a problem and I hope you can help me. I want to work with Magento, but there is a message that I can not solve. The massage is:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I've just got the same problem when trying to add key to configuration in Magento 2. You can follow these steps to fix your problem:

1. Download this file: 
   https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/blob/e9175fec5d0c4d42de24ed6d84a06d504d5e5a09/ca-bundle.crt
2. Put it somewhere. In my case that was E:\XAMPP\ directory.
3. Add these 2 lines to your php.ini file:

   > ```
   > curl.cainfo="E:/XAMPP/ca-bundle.crt"
   > openssl.cafile="E:/XAMPP/ca-bundle.crt"
   > ```
4. Restart Apache Server.